# Error occurred when importing the Html file in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

When I am importing the `HTML` File according to the tutorialpoint link `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsoup/jsoup_load_file.htm`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class jsoupTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        URL path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.htm");
        File input = new File(path.toURI());
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
        System.out.println(document.title());
    }
}
```

I got this error when I run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jsoupTester.main(jsoupTester.java:13)
```

**Note: jsoupTester.java file and temp.htm are in the same location**

May I know how to solve this issue? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, line #13 is the line that says: `path.toURI()`.  To tell you the truth, whenever I use `ClassLoader`, it is strictly for obtaining files inside of **`JAR Files`**.  Usually, when passing a **`URL`** to **`JSoup`**, make sure you type the complete **HTTP URL**, or the complete File-System File-Name.  Is this `test.htm` file inside of the JSoup Example **`JAR File`**?  Is this why you are using the **`Class Loader`**?  I cannot see a reason for using `ClassLoader`.  Try using `URL url = new URL("some page");` instead.

Comment: I didn't notice the link to the tutorial page you provided in your question.  Use the following for your **File** - as follows: `File input = new File("C:\\jsoup\\test.htm")` ... (assuming you have indeed followed the tutorial and saved a file to that directory with that content)...  I have never heard of using the `ClassLoader` to locat **`'.html' Files`** on the File-System... But who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the website properly? the code documentation showed this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupTester {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
      
      URL path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.htm");
      File input = new File(path.toURI());
      Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8"); // Only 2 parameters
      System.out.println(document.title());
   }
}
```

**Error**

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", ""); // 3rd parameter is not included in the documentation
```

As you can see the error is that you have another redundant parameter which I believe is causing the error. Remove that `""` in your code and it will work fine. Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: HIs **`NullPointerException`** is from this: `path.toURI()`